# Requirements for $b$ and $c$ in a equation system

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have following system of equations.

\begin{align}
cx + 2y &=1 \\
\frac23 x -y &=b
\end{align}
If $b$ and $c$ are real numbers , what are the requirements for $b$ and $c$ to get only one solution at the end?

Comment: A geometrical way of thinking about this might be helpful: these two are linear equations, so their graphs are straight lines on the plane. The condition that they have exactly one solution means that they cross, i.e. they should not be parallel but distinct  (in which case there would be no solution) and they should not lie on top of each other (in which case there would an infinite number of solutions). This does not help you *solve* the problem, but it does (IMO) clarify the situation.

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation $y = (1-cx)/2$. If you substitute that in the second, \begin{align}
2/3x-(1-cx)/2 &= b \\
2/3x - 1/2 + (c/2)x &= b \\
x(2/3+c/2) &= b + 1/2
\end{align}

From this, you can see that if $b+1/2 = 2/3 + c/2 = 0$, $x$ can take any value, thus not a unique solution. If you have that $b+1/2 \ne 0$ and $2/3+c/2 = 0$, then no value of $x$ will satisfy the equation.

Comment: First of all, thank you Zamarion for your detailed Answer and Lee David Chung Lin for the Edit. I am sorry for the bad format of my post, im quiet new here. But at the End i still dont understand what are the exact requirements for the coefficients b & c to get exact one solution at the end. Could you or someone else explain it a little bit further for me please?

Comment: In my answer, I showed on which conditions  the system has infinitely many solutions or zero solutions. If you want to have a unique solution, you need to make sure that these conditions are not met.